# Unsetting a path from LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: centos, path

When the centos boots up, there two paths in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I want to know where in in the startup these paths are added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

```
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/gridengine/lib/linux-x64:/opt/openmpi/lib
```

I want to permanently remove `/opt/openmpi/lib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably in your user account's `.bashrc`, e.g., after following instructions such as [Using R on Knot](http://csc.cnsi.ucsb.edu/docs/using-r-knot).  It is rare for an RPM to install using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so the place to look would be in user-customizations.

If you do not see it in `.bashrc`, then

```
cd /etc
grep -l -r /opt/openmpi/lib .
```

would be the next place to look, showing you filenames where the customization may have been made, e.g., `/etc/profile.d/*`

Comment: I found that `rocks-openmpi` module is loaded. How can I unload it? `# module list \\
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:\\
  1) rocks-openmpi
`

Comment: What you are searching for is `module unload rocks-openmpi`. But it is autoloaded somewhere like described by Thomas Dickey. You also may want to have a look at `man module`, especially to the `init*` sections.